# htaccess URL rewrite pattern format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a good look through all the other htaccess url rewrite questions, but all of them deal with the reverse of my problem.

The site I am working on takes content from child pages in WordPress and presents them as anchored sections on the parent page. The problem for the site now is that if Google (or the built in search, though that can probably be done in the templates) links to one of the child pages it will direct users to the single page rather than the correct section of the parent page.

I was hoping to come up with a URL rewrite pattern which would reformat the URL to what I need, but it doesn't seem to work... and I know that's because I have done it wrong!

The URL which needs to be rewritten is something like:

```
website.com/parent-page/child-page/
```

I need this to be rewritten to:

```
website.com/parent-page/?subpage=child-page
```

My initial stab at it looks like this, but I know I've misunderstood something about how to format the pattern.

```
RewriteRule ^/$1?subpage=$2      ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$
```

Can anyone help format this correctly or point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule    ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$        /$1/?subpage=$2   [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy... it doesn't appear to work for me, but that is more likely to do with the site possibly - however, I've managed to create a PHP redirect that seems to do the job instead!

Comment: Ok but handling it at the Apache level will likely be much more scalable than a PHP redirect. I've also fixed my rewriterule to remove the initial slash, thanks Croises.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# If the request is not for a valid file/directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/?subpage=$2   [QSA,L]
```

No initial `/` in `htaccess RewriteRule` first uri
And optional final `/`

Comment: Thanks, Croises... it doesn't appear to work for me, but that is more likely to do with the site possibly - however, I've managed to create a PHP redirect that seems to do the job instead!

Comment: Try now with `RewriteEngine on`

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess rewrites didn't seem to work, so I've created a PHP redirect instead by taking the page slug, page parent permalink and mashing the two together.

Not the most elegant solution, I expect, but it works.